# How to change optimization flags to build libraries for deployment?

Tags: macos, homebrew

When I deploy brew compiled libs on a core2 machine I get "BAD INSTRUCTION" error when starting the app which embeds the lib. I compiled it on an ivy bridge. How to I tell brew to use march=core2 instead of march=native or whatever brew is using?

Comment: Have you tried `brew edit <your lib name>`?

Comment: It is not saved inside the formular. It's done on a global level I think.

Comment: I don't know, this may help though... http://superuser.com/questions/493428/where-are-the-build-settings-in-homebrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by opening a issue at their bug tracker:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/31483

```
brew install --build-bottle
```

This build it for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
brew install openssl --bottle-arch=core2
```

Which is how bottles are built:

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Bottles.md